# How to convert VARCHARS into decimal/smallmoney that contains other characters

Tags: sql, function, ssms

I am trying to create a function that will get one character from an input and return a smallmoney.
When inputted 'kjkh 1.99 hkhj' it will return this error: **There is insufficient result space to convert a smallmoney value to varchar.**

EDIT: I changed the RETURNS to RETURNS SMALLMONEY and got
"Cannot convert char value to smallmoney. The char value has incorrect syntax."

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.StripNonNumerics
(
  @Temp varchar(40)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @KeepValues AS VARCHAR(40)
    SET @KeepValues = '%[^0-9].%'
    WHILE PATINDEX(@KeepValues, @Temp) > 0
        SET @Temp = STUFF(@Temp, PATINDEX(@KeepValues, @Temp), 1, '')
    
    RETURN (SELECT CAST(TRIM(@Temp) AS SMALLMONEY));
END;
```

FINAL EDIT: FIXED USING SET @KeepValues = '%[^0-9].%' TO
@KeepValues = '%[^0-9.]%'

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: https://www.red-gate.com/hub/product-learning/sql-prompt/avoid-use-money-smallmoney-datatypes

Answer (score 0):

Change @KeepValues = '%[^0-9].%' To @KeepValues = '%[^0-9.]%'